# How to filter null values with Kartik grid and select2 filter?

Tags: yii2, grid, jquery-select2, kartik-v

I'm trying to add a custom option to my select2 filter (kartik grid). This option is meant to select all rows where `something_id=null`. It's a simple crud generated grid, modified to use kartik grid and select2 filter instead of yii2 default grid/filter.

I tried doing this in my table2_id column:

`'filter' => [null => 'Nothing'] + Arrayhelper::map(Something::find()->orderBy('id)->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'thing')`

But this new "null" option is not showing in the menu. I assume for select2 null just mean no filter and select2 just shows the placeholder for that. I can't find any option in select2 documentation to modify this behavior. The generated html for this option is:

`<option value="" selected="" data-select2-id="5">Nothing</option>`

But the css has the property `visibility:hidden;`. So I tried using:

`'filter' => [0 => 'Nothing'] + Arrayhelper::map(Something::find()->orderBy('id)->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'thing')`

But I can't manage to properly translate `'something_id'=>0` into a `'something_id'=>null` condition neither in the controller or search model. Tried many things but everything failed at some point and I don't think my code deserves to be posted here, also I don't keep a copy of every failed piece of code so I'd like to ask what is the correct way of doing this from scratch. Thank you.

Comment: How about the custom query for data provider that runs the `null` filter when `id` is `0`?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do so. For example with

Comment: ```
 if(!is_null($this->something_id)){
     if ( $this->something_id == 0 ) {
  $query->andWhere(['something_id' => null]);
     }else{
  $query->andFilterWhere(['something_id' => $this->something_id]);
     }
 }
```

Comment: But it fails when I do exactly the same with a second column. If I only select "nothing" from "wathever" column filter, I always got:

```SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "table" WHERE ("something_id" IS NULL) AND ("wathever_id" IS NULL)```

Even if "something_id" is null (and not 0) in the search model when debuging this request.

Comment: Even if I try this ugly piece of code I have the same result when `$this->something_id` is null:

```
 if(!is_null($this->something_id)){
     if ( $this->something_id == 0 ) {
  $query->andWhere(['somethign_id' => null]);
     }else{
  $query->andFilterWhere(['something_id' => $this->something_id]);
     }
 }else{
     $query->andFilterWhere(['something_id' => $this->something_id]);
 }
```

Comment: I tried many things and for one reason or another I never got it. And yes, at least for this I don't care about writing nice code or fully understanding how yii2 woks. It's just old code I need to update and hopefully forever forget.

Answer (score 1):

Well, my answer got deleted because I made a joke. Here is the very very serious version of my answer.

```
// WatheverSearch.php
    if ( $this->something_id === '0' ) {
        $query->andWhere(['something_id' => null]);
    }else{
        $query->andFilterWhere(['something' => $this->something]);
    }
```